# How to search for a FHIR resource without a tag

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I've got an app where the user can tag QuestionnaireResponses with 'Green' if they've been cleared as OK, and also tag as Yellow and Red for follow-up. I'd like to make a page which shows all resources that are NOT tagged with Green (including those not tagged at all). Any idea how I do that on HAPI-FHIR?

From the documentation I'm guessing something like:

http://apps.ehelselab.com/baseDstu2/QuestionnaireResponse?_tag:not=http://fhir.ehelselab.com/codes/tags|Green

or

http://apps.ehelselab.com/baseDstu2/QuestionnaireResponse?_tag=nehttp://fhir.ehelselab.com/codes/tags|Green

But it doesn't seem to return a correct response. Does someone know the correct format?

Comment: My guess is that HAPI doesn't support this yet.  I've reached out to James to respond.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I've never actually seen the `:not` qualifier. Where is that defined?

HAPI definitely doesn't support this, but it wouldn't be too hard to add..

Edit: Oh, turns out it's documented in an [obvious spot](http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#token). Let me have a look at how bad this would be to implement.. I'd agree, we should support it.

Comment: It would be extremely useful for me at least. I've got a function where all untagged observations are listed, and then the health worker can tag it with different categories, removing it from the list.